PivotTable refresh macro when there are changes in the worksheet
My goal is to refresh the pivot tables of a worksheet, when changes are done to some cells. These cells contain percentages which influence the pivot tables, and are the only cells that are edited.
This is the code I have so far, but when I run it, it gives me this error: "Run-time error '424': Object required", and it points to Line 4.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim PT As PivotTable

        For Each PT In Worksheet.PivotTables
            PivotTable.PivotCache.Refresh
        Next PT
    
End Sub

I suspect it may be a syntax error, and some fault at my end, but I cannot figure it out.
I tried refresh all, and it works of course, but I have multiple queries in different sheets and only want to refresh all the pivot tables. At first I wrote PT as PivotTable, in the for-loop, thinking it was sufficient, but it gave me this error, after which I added  Dim PT As PivotTable, which did not solve the issue.

I did this once and immediately removed it.  One copy/paste of ~1500 rows with ~20 columns of data and things went south very fast (30,000+ Workbook_Change events firing was BAD).  Determine which specific cells ( you should be able to narrow it down to a specific cell) being changed should trigger the Refresh.

I added the marked solution, as well as a cell constraint. I see your point, but the Sheet is not meant for Data storage, it is an Overview sheet, that only contains Pivot tables and those changable Percentages. In the beginning I did not think, it would be necessary to limit the Code to specific cells, but I am rather safe than sorry.

Here's some code to refresh the pivot cache of each pivot table on the sheet:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    
    For Each pt In PivotTables
        pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    Next pt

End Sub

Normally, you would need to qualify the reference to the PivotTables collection with a reference to the worksheet object which contains that collection.  As you're writing this code in a worksheet module, the reference to the worksheet object is implicit.
If you did want to qualify the reference to the PivotTables collection you could say:
For Each pt in Me.PivotTables

The problem was that you were saying Worksheet.PivotTables.  Worksheet is the name of a class, not a reference to a specific worksheet object which is what you needed here.
You also almost certainly want to check if the cells that were changed are within the specific range containing the percentages:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    
    'Check if the cell changed is in P1:Q2, if not, exit the sub
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("P1:Q2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    For Each pt In PivotTables
        pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    Next pt

End Sub

